# how to use steps within a table element in ant design?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, antd

I want to have timeline(here i am using step element) inside my table content. Can anyone help me telling how to place an ant element within another

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Steps, Divider, Table } from 'antd';

const { Step } = Steps;
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'AAA',
  },
  {
    title: 'BBB',
  },
  {
    title: 'CCC',
  },
  {
    title: 'DDD',
  },
  {
    title: 'EEE',
  },
  {
    title: 'FFF',
  },
];
class requestorDashboard extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="progress-level">
          <Table columns={columns} >
            <td>
              <Steps progressDot current={1}>
                  <Step title="Finished" description="xxx" />
                  <Step title="In Progress" description=" yyy" />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" zzz" />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" xyz@gmail.com " />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" abc @gmail.com " />
              </Steps>
            </td>
            <td>
              <Steps progressDot current={1}>
                  <Step title="Finished" description="xxx" />
                  <Step title="In Progress" description=" yyy" />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" zzz" />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" xyz@gmail.com " />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" abc @gmail.com " />
              </Steps>
            </td>
          </Table>         
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default requestorDashboard;

This doesn't work. The table body is empty when compiled.

Answer (score 0):

The column props support a custom [render](https://ant.design/components/table/) prop that can be used to render custom JSX within the column's cells. For example:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: 'AAA',
    render: (text, record) => (<Steps progressDot current={1}>
                  <Step title="Finished" description="xxx" />
                  <Step title="In Progress" description=" yyy" />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" zzz" />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" xyz@gmail.com " />
                  <Step title="Waiting" description=" abc @gmail.com " />
              </Steps>)
  },
  {
    title: 'BBB',
  },
  {
    title: 'CCC',
  },
  {
    title: 'DDD',
  },
  {
    title: 'EEE',
  },
  {
    title: 'FFF',
  },
];

...

<Table columns={columns} dataSource={someArrayOfData}/>
```

This would render all those steps in every cell in the 'AAA' column.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But this is ain't working. am getting am empty table body . Should i define the render method somewhere ?

Comment: You'd need to remove all the steps you're manually putting in the Table body and also add a ```dataSource``` so it actually has data to display. I added a basic example